# Ruby regex anchors combined with character class &&

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to match a string containing printable ascii without some special characters, for example the character 'x'. I use this regex `/[.&&[^x]]/` for this task.

When trying to match if the whole string is made from this character specification the regex doesn't match any more. `/^[.&&[^x]]*$/`

Trying this with the normal dot works however.
`/^.*$/` matches every string i throw at it.

I'm using Ruby 2.7.2

The regex is constructed at runtime and the `/^ ... $/` anchors are needed for other edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printable ASCII regex is `[ -~]`.

To match any printable ASCII char other than `x`, just use character class subtraction on this class: `[ -~&&[^x]]`.

To match a string that only contains such chars use

```rb
/\A[ -~&&[^x]]*\z/
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/HIINL3CWAaUw0E).

Comment: Thanks, your solution works, but I'm trying to understand why my code doesn't work. I think '.' inside square brackets only matches the actual dot character, it looses its special meaning.
`"..." =~ /^[.&&[^x]]*$/` actually matches.

Comment: @meschi Because `/[.]/` = `/\./`, i.e. `[.]` only matches a dot. Subtracting `x` from dot does not make much sense. At any rate, `.` does not match "printable ASCII". `.` matches any char other than a newline char.